n keys for n doors
I need help with the following exercise:
You are standing in front of n locked doors. In your hand, you hold a keyring with n identical-looking keys, each of which opens exactly one of the doors. Whenever you successfully unlock a door, you remove the corresponding key from the keyring. How many attempts do you need on average (expected value) to open all the doors if you:
(a) Drop the keyring after each attempt and lose track of which keys you've already tried?
(b) Can remember after each attempt which keys you have already tried on that door?
Before proceeding to (b) I would like to solve (a) of course. So my idea for part (a) is:
let $T_i$ denote the number of attempts needed to unlock the $i$-th door.
Each time we try out a key on a door this represents a Bernoulli-Experiment with probability $p=\frac{1}{n-i+1}$
Thus, $T_i$ follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p_i$
We know then
$$\mathbb{E}[T_i] = \frac{1}{p} = n-i+1$$
now I sum up the expectation values for each door:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[T_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} n-i+1 = n(n+1)-\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$
is this correct?

In (a) are you dropping the keyring after extracting the successful key, or the entire keyring ?

if you are extracting a successful key you just end up with one key less and go to the next door

The answer to part (a) is correct

what do you get for part (b)?
I have $\frac{n^2+3n}{4}$

For $(b)$ note that the key to the first door is equally likely to be in any of the $n$ positions, making the expected number of trials you need to unlock the first door $\frac {n+1}2$.  As before, you just need to sum over the the doors.

yes, I did it like this and then ended up with the above expression - mind to verify?

Yes, It is $\frac {n(n+3)}4$.  But I suggest editing your post to include that, or posting your solution below.  The comments won't stay up, that's not what they are for.

Answers were found with the help of @lulu and @trueblueanil in the comments:
Part a) is correct as it was written in the OG post
Part b) $\frac{n\cdot(n+3)}{4}$ is obtained by the following strategy as mentioned by @lulu:
For () note that the key to the first door is equally likely to be in any of the  positions, making the expected number of trials you need to unlock the first door $\frac{n+1}{2}$. As before, you just need to sum over the the doors.
